# Image not inserted from android to MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, image, android-studio, android-image

I need seriously help !!

I use below code to get the image from gallery and finally insert it into `MySQL` through `php`. Image will get from Activity B, and finally return to Activity A and save into MySQL once the button in Activity A is clicked.

**Activity B**

```
 Uri selectedImage;
 private Uri imageUri;
ImageView imageView;

     private void activeGallery() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }


  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
                if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK & null != data) {
                    selectedImage = data.getData();
                    imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
                }

                break;

 submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // back to Activity A
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                amount = Amount.getText().toString();
                description = Description.getText().toString();
                type = spinnerType.getSelectedItem().toString();
                returnIntent.putExtra("type", type);
                returnIntent.putExtra("description", description);
                returnIntent.putExtra("amount", amount);
                if(selectedImage!=null) {
                    returnIntent.putExtra("img_uri", selectedImage.toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    returnIntent.putExtra("img_uri", Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.project.myapplication/mipmap/no_image").toString());
                }
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

**Activity A** (Image and text can be returned from B to A)

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity B and populate ListView A
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                ReceiveType = data.getStringExtra("type");
                ReceiveDescription = data.getStringExtra("description");
                ReceiveAmount = data.getStringExtra("amount");
                imgURI = Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra("img_uri"));
                // Toast.makeText(getApplication(),ReceiveType+ReceiveAmount+ReceiveDescription+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (mClickedPosition == -1) {  // if icon clicked
                    if (obj != null)
                        obj.addNewItem(ReceiveType, ReceiveAmount, imgURI, ReceiveDescription);
                     addOrRemoveFooter();

                } else {
                    if (obj != null)
                     obj.changeItem(mClickedPosition, ReceiveType, ReceiveAmount, imgURI, ReceiveDescription);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here comes to the interesting part. When submit button in Activity A, is clicked

```
 public void uploadImageAndText(ArrayList<ImageAndText> listItems, final String id) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            try {
                for (ImageAndText i : listItems) {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                    String type = i.getType();
                    String[] Type = type.split(":");
                    object.put("type", Type[1]);
                   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Type[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String amount = i.getAmount();
                    String[] Amount = amount.split(":");
                    object.put("amount", Amount[1]);
                    String description = i.getDescription();
                    String[] Description = description.split(":");
                    object.put("description", Description[1]);
                    String image=i.getImage().toString();
                    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(image);
                    object.put("image", image);
                    object.put("ts_id", id);
                    object.put(Configs.KEY_IMAGE,getStringImage(imageUri));
                    jsonArray.put(object);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            AddStaff ru = new AddStaff(jsonArray);
            ru.execute();

        }

        class AddStaff extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            JSONArray jsonArray;

            AddStaff(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(AddClaims.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    data.put("listItems", jsonArray.toString());
                    //Log.d("log", "This json = " + jsonArray.toString());
                    RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                    String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Configs.STAFF_BENEFIT, data);
                    return result;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return "";
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


        public String getStringImage(Uri imgUri) {

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imgUri);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
                return encodedImage;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            return "";
        }
    }
```

I did many test here. If the selected image is from `download` or `whatsapp`, it can be inserted. If I select the image from `My photos` , no image will be inserted. Why would this happen ???

SaffBenefit.php

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        if( !empty( $_POST['listItems'] ) ){
            $listItems = json_decode( $_POST['listItems'], true ); 
            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "spiral69_wp178", "q1w2e3r4", "spiral69_androiddb");
            if( $mysqli->connect_errno ) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL";
            $sql="INSERT INTO `staff_benefit` 
                 ( `type`, `amount`, `description`, `image`, `ts_id` ) 
                  VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
            if($stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql )){
                $url="http://www.ss.com/Android/CRUD/PhotoUpload/";
                foreach( $listItems as $item ){ 
                    $id = uniqid();
                    $image_name = $id.".png";
                    $save_path = 'PhotoUpload/'.$image_name;
                    $image_url = $url.$image_name;
                    $bytes=file_put_contents($save_path, base64_decode($item['image']));
                    if( !$bytes ){
                        echo 'Error saving image';  
                    }else{
                        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', 
                        $item['type'], 
                        $item['amount'], 
                        $item['description'], 
                        $image_url, 
                        $item['ts_id'] );
                        if( !$res=$stmt->execute()){ 
                            echo 'Query failed with code: '.$stmt->errno;
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
            $mysqli->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you see any exception when you select the image from `My photos`

Comment: Do you mean I need to add  try catch ?

Comment: No, I am asking that when you try to insert the photo from local storage then is there any exception? It looks like that you are getting OutOfMemory exception.  Please confirm that.

Comment: @MustansarSaeed no exception is shown

Comment: @MustansarSaeed can I use a try and catch to confirm ?

Comment: You are saying that no exception is occuring then there is no point of try catch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102561/discussion-between-mustansar-saeed-and-john-joe).

Comment: I see this  `Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system !!!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be the issue that `base64 encode data` is too high which you are sending to server and `MySql` is unable to handle. What you should do is change the compression value to `70%` as `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos);`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have given write external storage permissions in manifest file. Read alone doesnt work when you are trying to send a copy to server.

Comment: I have  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />